# Bar with negative and neutral stack

Tags: highcharts

I would like to display answers of type "yes/no/don't know". I was thinking about something similair to Bar with negative stack, but with "don't know" as a neutral part in the middle with equal width on both sides of zero. To show what I mean I added two neutral series to the standard fiddle. How can I merge them into one neutral series in the middle?

```
{
        name: 'Neutral',
        data: [...]
}
```

Maybe I'm on the completely wrong track. Any suggestions?

[modified Bar with negative stack-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burktelefon/3jn0mLs9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do this with [`columnrange`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnrange) series that is inverted (to look like bar chart). This does require the `highcharts-more.js` library as well.
You need to set the index for each question (`x`), the low value (`low`), the high value (`high`), and then the color you would want (`color`).

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'columnrange',
    inverted: true
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Q1', 'Q2']
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Answers',
    data: [
    // Question 1
        {
        x: 0,
        low: -10,
        high: -5,
        color: 'red'
      }, {
        x: 0,
        low: -5,
        high: 5,
        color: 'blue'
      }, {
        x: 0,
        low: 5,
        high: 10,
        color: 'green'
      },
      // Question 2
      {
        x: 1,
        low: -15,
        high: -2,
        color: 'red'
      }, {
        x: 1,
        low: -2,
        high: 8,
        color: 'blue'
      }, {
        x: 1,
        low: 8,
        high: 20,
        color: 'green'
      }
    ]
  }]

});
```

Sample [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gpvvs267/).